# Is there any way to add custom column to sessions table while working with pdo sessions in symfony 4?

Tags: php, session, pdo, symfony-4.2

I Just configure Pdo sessions with symfony which work absolutely fine for me but now i am looking to add some extra fields like user IP, user id etc for make a report later on for which user login from which area so i find no way to add new columns into sessions table as it's working is little bit different

```
  //services.yaml
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler:
        arguments:

            - !service { class: PDO, factory: 'database_connection:getWrappedConnection' }
            - { lock_mode: 1 }
//framework.yaml 
session:
        enabled: true
        gc_maxlifetime: 36000 #10 hours custom session time
        handler_id: 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler'
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
        cookie_secure: auto
        cookie_samesite: lax


//database table
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
    `sess_id` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `sess_data` BLOB NOT NULL,
    `sess_time` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `sess_lifetime` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL
) COLLATE utf8_bin, ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by Creating Third Table by Name User Logs and Pass Session ID and User ID into it ( session and User table already created ) and some extra fields like ip location and so on. whenever user login make entry into this table